# copy sharepoint top navigation bar to another site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two sitecollection A and B, i want to write a c# code on my webpart to read the topnavbar of sitecollection A in sitecollection B and display the same in ASPMenu control on site collection B –

Comment: You would probably get better responses posting this question on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnodecollection(v=office.12).aspx